# How to work in Rails with accepts_nested_attributes_for, has_many through and a form for edit or create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, controller, associations, has-many-through

I'm working on a CRUD with 3 models and accepts_nested_attributes_for, I'm trying to save on bd the record of a model loan_policy and in the join table besides the respective id's and the id of a stored model which is process_flow a column which name is behavior, but I can't figure out how to do it, correctly.

I already have the 3 models involved in addition in which despite showing correctly the information I can not save correctly in the bd, keeping in mind that the process_flow model already has the values ​​in the bd stored.

The Models

```
class LoanPolicy < ApplicationRecord    
 has_many :loan_policy_process_flows
 has_many :process_flows, through: :loan_policy_process_flows
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :loan_policy_process_flows
end

class ProcessFlow < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :loan_policy_process_flows
 has_many :loan_policies, through: :loan_policy_process_flows
end

class LoanPolicyProcessFlow < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :loan_policy
 belongs_to :process_flow
end
```

The Controller

```
def new
 @loan_policy = LoanPolicy.new
end

def create
    @loan_policy = LoanPolicy.new(loan_policy_params)
    if @loan_policy.save!
        flash[:success] = 'Política Creada con Exito'
        redirect_to loan_policies_path
    else
        flash[:danger] = "Política No Creada"
        redirecto_to new_loan_policy_path
    end
    
end

def loan_policy_params
        params.require(:loan_policy).permit(
            :name,
            :description,
            :legal_document_id,
            :status,
            :minimun_range,
            :maximun_range,
            :minimun_days,
            :maximun_days,
            :monthly_interest_rate,
            :external_bureau_required,
            :credit_bureau_id,
            loan_policy_process_flows_attributes: [:process_flow_id, :behavior])
end
```

The _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_with(model: loan_policy, local: true) do |form| %>
  ....
  <% ProcessFlow.all.each_with_index do |process_flow, i| %>

   <% if i == 0 %>

     <div class="col-5 col-md-5"><label class="control-label">Proceso</label></div>
     <div class="col-6 col-md-6"><label class="control-label">Comportamiento</label></div>

     <br>

     <div class="col-5 col-md-5">
      <%= check_box_tag "loan_policy[loan_policy_process_flows_attributes][][process_flow_id]", process_flow.id, @loan_policy.process_flow_ids.include?(process_flow.id), id: dom_id(process_flow) %>
      <%= label_tag dom_id(process_flow), process_flow.process_description %>

     </div>

     <div class="col-6 col-md-6">
      <%= select_tag "loan_policy[loan_policy_process_flows_attributes][][behavior]", options_for_select([['Seleccione Comportamiento', nil], ['Manual', 'Manual'], ['Automático', 'Automático']], selected: "loan_policy[process_flow_ids][behavior]" ), class: 'form-control', id: "process_flow_select_picker_"+dom_id(process_flow)%>
     </div>

   <% else %>

     <br>
     <div class="col-5 col-md-5">
      <%= check_box_tag "loan_policy[loan_policy_process_flows_attributes][][process_flow_id]", process_flow.id, @loan_policy.process_flow_ids.include?(process_flow.id), id: dom_id(process_flow), class: 'check_input' %>
      <%= label_tag dom_id(process_flow), process_flow.process_description %>
     </div>
     
     <div class="col-6 col-md-6">
      <%= select_tag "loan_policy[loan_policy_process_flows_attributes][][behavior]", options_for_select([['Seleccione Comportamiento', nil], ['Manual', 'Manual'], ['Automático', 'Automático']], selected: "loan_policy[process_flow_ids][behavior]" ), class: 'form-control', id: "process_flow_select_picker_"+dom_id(process_flow)%>
      </div>
                                            
   <% end %>

 <% end %>

<% end %>
```

The parameters that are being sent:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"9qK5ay2oFK86UgZ3srzR5tYG6JOCK8BQRkjpWOJG+4NYQ+A+fKI6UB29GLi9e8xlVEFho5Od6DB71QJWRzRa5g==", "loan_policy"=>{"name"=>"Policita 2", "status"=>"true", "legal_document_id"=>"4", "minimun_range"=>"120", "maximun_range"=>"2200", "minimun_days"=>"25", "maximun_days"=>"60", "monthly_interest_rate"=>"0.3", "credit_bureau_id"=>"3", "external_bureau_required"=>"Si", "loan_policy_process_flows_attributes"=>[{"process_flow_id"=>"1", "behavior"=>"Manual"}, {"behavior"=>"", "process_flow_id"=>"3"}, {"behavior"=>"Automático"}, {"behavior"=>"", "process_flow_id"=>"5"}, {"behavior"=>"Manual"}, {"behavior"=>""}, {"behavior"=>""}]}, "commit"=>"Continuar"}
```

The error

> Validation failed: Loan policy process flows process flow must exist

what I would also like to do in loan_policy_process_flows_attributes would be a hash with the ids that were selected and the behavior of the respective select.

Thanks.

Comment: For starters you would need to add `:loan_policy_id` to `loan_policy_process_flows_attributes:` array in the controller strong params to allow the `loan_policy_id` through. That is for the `Unpermitted parameter` error you are getting. Like `loan_policy_process_flows_attributes: [:process_flow_id, :behavior, :loan_policy_id]`

Comment: I update the question, I resolve some stuffs, but still when a pick from the check_box for example three of them, throws the error, but if i pick all check boxes the record save on bd correctly.

Comment: For better understanding, I show the parameters and the Question. Tanhks